# Parallelise double loop as an array job (Matlab + bash)

Tags: bash, matlab

I have a double loop in Matlab. I would like your help  to parallelise it as an **array job** with a **bash file** to be **qsub** in the HPC of my university.

**IMPORTANT 1**: I **cannot** use parfor because I don't have Matlab parallel toolbox.

**IMPORTANT 2**: Please don't pay too much attention to the content of the code. It is a silly example, which does not clearly require any parallelisation. My actual code is much more complicated and I cannot report it here. I can reassure you that parallelising as an array job is the most efficient solution for my specific case.

---

This is the original Matlab file that I would like to parallelise.

```
clear
rng default

m=4;
n=2;
A=randn(m,n);
g=5;
B=randn(g,n);

result=cell(m,1);
for i=1:m %LOOP 1
    result{i}=zeros(g,n);
    for h=1:g %LOOP 2
        result{i}(h,:)=A(i,:)+B(h,:);
    end
end
```

---

I know how to parallelise as an array job the outer loop (LOOP 1). I can do that as follows.

**1) FILE main.m**

```
clear
rng default

m=4;
n=2;
A=randn(m,n);

g=5;
B=randn(g,n);

workers=m; %number of parallel workers
jobs=1; %number of jobs per parallel worker
```

**2) FILE f_s.m**

```
%% Select local part of A
idtemp=str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'));
A_local=A(jobs*(idtemp-1)+1: idtemp*jobs,:);

%% Do the job
result=zeros(g,n);
for h=1:g
    result(h,:)=A_local+B(h,:);
end

%% Save the job                      
filename = sprintf('result.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename,'result')
```

**2) qsub the following bash file in the terminal of the HPC:**

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=3G
#$ -l tmem=3G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 4 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 4
#$ -t 1-4

#$ -N example
date
hostname


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

/share/apps/matlabR2018b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f_s; exit"
```

**QUESTION:** How can I parallelise also the inner loop (LOOP 2) using **the same array-job technique above** (**NOT PARFOR**)? Basically, I would like **another "tree"** opening from `f_s.m`. What I'm unsure about is how to set the new SGE_TASK_ID.

Comment: MATLAB has very powerful pararel tools. For example it will use thread level parallelization for most inbuilds (I have used it with 64 cores and it uses all of them for basic operations, such as matrix multiplication). On top of that, it has `parfor` to parallelize for loops. Why skip all that and use bash?

Comment: Right, bu tlaunching 200 instances of MATLABis much slower than 1 MATLAB launching 200 treads. Where is the point where launching MATLAB instances is worth it? I don't know. In any case, as always, what is the best approach to take in parallelization is always mostly influenced by the code itself, so I can't advise more in the topic, as the real code would be needed.

Comment: Sure was just trying to help. Half of the people asking in the page always ask about an attempted solution to a problem, rather than the problem it self, and often that attempt is misguided. You seem to know what you are doing, it was just not obvious that you did skip the easy way of `parfor` unnecessarily, but now it is. Good luck.

Comment: You can use the same scheme for both loops, but it will be more complicated to put all your data back together. Simply consider the two loops as a single loop that iterates `m*g` times, and your task ID is `i*g+h`.

Answer (score 2):

You said "NOT PARFOR", but I'm going to ignore that because your comments indicate (to me, at least) that `parfor` is definitely the right tool for the job here (I would say that as I wrote the feature I'm about to recommend you to use ;) ). But I'm going to keep this brief because if you don't have a MATLAB Parallel Server licence available, then the following isn't going to work out. But here's what you would do if MATLAB Parallel Server is available. (This will use SGE job arrays behind the scenes, and lets you use nice `parfor` syntax to set things up)

1. Structure your code as a `parfor` loop, and test locally to make sure it all works on a small scale
2. Set up your client so that it can talk to your SGE cluster, following the instructions [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52816-parallel-computing-toolbox-plugin-for-matlab-parallel-server-with-grid-engine).
3. Use [parforOptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parforoptions.html) to scale up to running the `parfor` loop directly on the cluster, a bit like this.

---

```
pfo = parforOptions(parcluster('mySgeProfile'));
parfor (idx = 1:N, pfo)
    out(idx) = myLongRunningThing(idx);
end
```

The `parforOptions` object lets you customise quite a bit about how things run on the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use parfor, as stated in my question. I want to "manually" build a second array job for my inner loop.

Comment: @user3285148: but you said in a comment that “In the HPC of my university parfor allows me to call at most 12 parallel workers within a node after queuing for long.” This might be the default configuration, but you can change that as indicated in this answer. If the license is available, then this should be the approach you should use.

Comment: Thanks, but once again I cannot use parfor. I need to request a special access to the HPC of my university (which takes time) for using it. Further, it is not an efficient solution for my actual case.